# how to show changes of an edited file in Coldfusion in localhost?

Tags: html, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

Newbie question...

I have setup an application using Coldfusion/MySQL/Apached Webserver on my localhost.

I can open and navigate through the application. But when I edit any .cfm file and refresh the browser window, nothing happens.

Since this is my first day with Coldfusion... I guess I'm missing something.

Anyone can give me a hint :-)

Thanks!

Comment: and browser cache is turned off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably stating the obvious, but try clearing the cache on your browser if you haven't already.  If that doesn't work, try logging into the ColdFusion Administrator, and under Server Settings click the "Clear Template Cache Now" button.  If that still doesn't fix your problem you can restart ColdFusion.  I'm guessing if you clear the browser cache that will do the trick though ;)

Comment: strange... Everything I do on the index.cfm, nothing happens. On other pages everything updates correct. Thx for the admin hint. Let's see if this helps on index.cfm...